# I can't connect TableViewCell button to TableViewController! How do I connect values from TableViewCell to TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, viewcontroller

From what I understand, I can not connect the button in my cell to my TableViewController using an outlet connection. **I can however** connect the button in my cell to my TableView using an action connection. This is the root of my huge problems.

In my cell I have a textview, an imageView with overlaid button, and a send button. **THIS IS THE CELL**

[image]

I assign an image to the imageView using imagePicker. imagePicker must be opened from the tableViewController (it can not be opened in the cell).

```
var MyImage = UIImage?()
var MyName = String()
var MyStatus = String()

// This is ImgButton that overlays the imageView
@IBAction func MyImageButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

// Select Image
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
// The image chosen by the user is now called MyImage
     MyImage = image
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Now when the send button is tapped, I make MyImage a PFFile for Parse.com and send it to the database. I don't need to give full details here. This part works fine.

**The problem is** that I don't know how to properly connect the cell to the tableViewController in a way that I can transfer values from one to the other. I want to get the textView.text from the cell, to the tableViewController so that from there I can send it to database with the image. The other problem is that, although the user can select an image and send it to database, *they can't get the selected image into their imageView*.

This is my attempt to connect the cell to the tableViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyStatusTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyStatusTableViewCell

    cell.MyName.text = MyName

    return cell
}
```

I was hoping that his code meant that MyName is now the variable that contains the .text that the user input in the textView.text in the cell. I tried sending MyName to the database but it came up empty.

**How do I get the textView.text from the tableViewCell into my database?**

Comment: I have also tried using the one send button to perform two functions: send the image to database from the ViewController and send the .text to database from the cell, but it wouldn't let me do that

Answer (score 1):

u can set tag of each element of UITableViewCell and then u can access it in cellForRowAtIndexPath like

```
if let textfield = cell.viewWithTag(21) as? UITextField {
    textfield.text = MyName
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code. MyName is still not equal to the user text input in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create IBAction instead of IBOutlet and in button action you can convert sender to position and find index path like this

```
 @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPos)!

    print("indexPath->\(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem which is inside your `UITableView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You have to load your custom cells like that below:-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyStatusTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyStatusTableViewCell
if cell == nil{

//Here you have to load your custom cells like that below
let array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyStatusTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
cell = array[0] as?  MyStatusTableViewCell
}
cell.MyName.text = "MyName" //Now it will set your textview value
return cell
}
```